# How to call Magento API Login Method in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Can Any Body tell How to call login method of megnto api in iphone 
i have done it in andriod using the xmlrpc library

```
// ...
String sessionId = "";
//HashMap<string , String> params = new HashMap</string><string , String>();
//params.put("apiUser", "developer");
//params.put("apiKey", "magento123");
XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://some-site.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc/");
try {
    /*
        sessionId = (String)client.callEx("login", new Object[]{params});
        will cause
        DEBUG/MY_XMLRPCException_MSG(196): XMLRPC Fault: Calling parameters do not match signature 1
    */
    sessionId = (String)client.call("login", "developer", "magento123");
    Log.d("MY_XMLRPC_SUCCESS_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
}
catch (XMLRPCException e) {
    Log.d("MY_XMLRPCException_MSG", e.getMessage());
}
```

I am newbie to iphone how can i do in iphone plz any body can tell and library or example that lead me to do what i want!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution , I am using the AFNetworking lib from git hub using that i am using following library That is given in following link 
https://github.com/lognllc/LogNMagento

Some Basic Step

=> Import the LogNMangento Application in your application

=> In magento.h
   **- (void)settingLogin:(completionBlock) completionBlock;**

=> In magento.m

```
- (void)settingLogin:(completionBlock)completionBlock
{

standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
array =[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];

client = [[MagentoClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:0]]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@"urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[SoapRequestOperation class]];
[SoapRequestOperation addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 301)]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[client postPath:@"login" parameters:@{@"username":[array objectAtIndex:1], @"apiKey": [array objectAtIndex:2] }  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    sessionID = responseObject;
    completionBlock(sessionID);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationData, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Response is not get");
    sessionID = FAILED_SESSION;
    completionBlock(sessionID);
}];

}
```

=> Call this in you class

```
[Magento.service settingLogin:^(NSString *session) {
            if(session){

                NSLog(@"Session %@",session);
                if(![session isEqualToString:@"NULL"])
                {
                    [self.view hideToastActivity];


                  self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self.view hideToastActivity];
                    [self.view makeToast:@"Please Check Store Info"];
                    session=nil;
                }
            }
            else{

            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.view makeToast:@"Please insert data"
                    duration:1.0
                    position:@"bottom"
                       ];
    }
```

And yes also make some change in INIT of magento.m in base url

Comment: It would be great if you could post the few lines that you used with AFNetworking - would be a big help to me and probably other!

Comment: @DavidH , i will post some code here . That is  i am using in Magento Api call. Have you seen above the LogNMagento Example , That is help a lot

Comment: I tried with LogNMagento but having no luck - it appears to use a SOAP interface - do all Magentos support that? Ultimately I will use the REST interface.

Comment: I have made some change in that library according to my requirement, first i want to call login the method and then get all order from megento api. As i am new to this iphone development , i did not know what to do. I think all magento support  SOAP

Comment: I can not find this method in Magento.h file or .m file  - (void)settingLogin:(completionBlock) completionBlock;